# Testable code: Attach event handler in constructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

as for my understanding, part of writing (unit-)testable code, a constructor should not do real work in constructor and only assigning fields. This worked pretty well so far. But I came across with a problem and I'm not sure what is the best way to solve it. See the code sample below.

```
class SomeClass
{
    private IClassWithEvent classWithEvent;

    public SomeClass(IClassWithEvent classWithEvent)
    {
        this.classWithEvent = classWithEvent;

        // (1) attach event handler in ctor.
        this.classWithEvent.Event += OnEvent;
    }

    public void ActivateEventHandling()
    {
        // (2) attach event handler in method
        this.classWithEvent.Event += OnEvent;
    }

    private void OnEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
    }
}
```

For me option (1) sounds fine, but it the constructor should only assign fields. Option (2) feels a bit "too much".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think I was in a rush to answer this one :) (if you cannot see my answer that's because it is deleted)

Comment: lol ditto. need more coffee.

Answer (score 4):

A unit test would test `SomeClass` at most. Therefore you would typically mock classWithEvent. Using some kind of injection for classWithEvent in ctor is fine.
Just as Thomas Weller said wiring is field assignment.

Option 2 is actually bad IMHO. As if you omit a call to `ActivateEventHandling` you end up with a improperly initialized class and need to transport knowledge of the requirement to call `ActivateEventHandling` in comments or somehow else, which make the class harder to use and probably results in a class-usage that was not even tested by you, as you have called `ActivateEventHandling` and tested it but an uninformed user omitting the activation didn't, and you have certainly not tested your class when `ActivateEventHandling` was not called, right? :)

**Edit: There may be alternative approaches here which are worth mentioning it**

Depending on the paradigm it may be wise to avoid wiring events in the class at all. I need to relativize my comment on Stephen Byrne's answer.

Wiring can be regarded as context knowledge. The [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) says a class should do only one task. Furthermore a class can be used more versatile if it does not have a dependency to something else. A very loosely coupled system would provide many classes witch have events and handlers and do not know other classes.

The environment is then responsible for wiring all the classes together to connect events properly with handlers. 
The environment would create the context in which the classes interact with each-other in a meaningful way.
A class in this case does therefore not know to whom it will be bound and it actually does not care. If it requires a value, it asks for it, whom it asks should be unknown to it. In that case there wouldn't even be an interface injected into the ctor to avoid a dependency. This concept is similar to neurons in a brain as they also emit messages to the environment and expect answer not knowing neighbouring neurons.

However I regard a dependency to an interface, if it is injected by some means of a dependency injection container just another paradigm and not less wrong.

The non trivial task of the environment to wire up all classes on start may lead to runtime errors (which are mitigated by a very good test coverage of functional and integration tests, which may be a hard task for large projects) and it gets very annoying if you need to wire dozens of classes and probably hundreds of events on startup manually.
While I agree that wiring in an environment and not in the class itself can be nice, it is not practical for large scale code.

Ralf Westphal (one of the founders of the [clean code developer initiative (sorry german only)](http://www.clean-code-developer.de/)) has written a software that performs the wiring automatically in a concept called "event based components" (not necessarily coined by himself). It uses naming conventions and signature matching with reflection to bind events and handlers together.

Comment: Just for the record, I have deleted my answer as it won't actually work using Moq - it was off top of head and => not a suitable answer. However it *is* possible to verify using RhinoMocks that an event handler was attached to.

Answer (score 2):

Wiring events *is* field assignment (because delegates are nothing but simple reference variables that point to methods).

So option(1) is fine.

Comment: but it is also an assignment to field in another object, so does not really apply here

Comment: @catbert Why wouldn't it? It doesn't matter where the assigned field resides as long as the assignment serves the only purpose to correctly initialize the instance.

Answer (score 1):

The point of constructor is not to "assign fields". It is to *establish invariants* of your object, i. e. something that never changes during its lifetime.

So if in other methods of class you depend on being always subscribed to some object, you'd better do it in the constructor.

On the other hand, if subscriptions come and go (probably not the case here), you can move this code to another method.

Comment: I never thought about that the constructor's job is to _establish invariants_. And this makes totally sense! You can also call it _setup the object's dependencies_: In my case, the dependency is the event `classWithEvent.Event` (and not the object `classWithEvent` itself). But as you cannot pass the event directly as ctor parameter, option (1) is the way to go. btw: I don't mark the answer as my accepted answer yet cause I want to wait for other comments and maybe I change my mind :)

Answer (score 0):

The single responsibility principle dictates that  that wiring should be avoided. Your class should not care how, or where from it receives data. It would make sense to rename OnEvent method to something more meaningful, and make it public.

Then some other class (bootstrapper, configurator, whatever) should be responsible for the wiring. Your class should only be responsible for what happens when a new data come's in.

Pseudo code:

```
public interface IEventProvider //your IClassWithEvent
{
   Event MyEvent...
}

public class EventResponder : IEventResponder
{
   public void OnEvent(object sender, EventArgs args){...}
}

public class Boostrapper
{
   public void WireEvent(IEventProvider eventProvider, IEventResponder eventResponder)
  {
      eventProvider>event += eventResponder.OnEvent;
  }
}
```

Note, the above is pseudo code, and it's only for the purpose to describe the idea.

How your bootstrapper actually is implemented depends on many things. It can be your "main" method, or your global.asax, or whatever you have in place to actually configure and prepare your application.

The idea is, that whatever is responsible to prepare the application to run, should compose it, not the classes themselves, as they should be as single purpose as possible, and should not care too much about how and where they are used.

Comment: Could you give a simple code example. Then it's more clear how this can look like. Side note: The names are more general and I totally agree that those are not acceptable in production code.

Comment: What are the requirements? Is there a hard requirement which says that your class need to be subscribed only to events from ClassWithEvents? Or it will work no matter what is raising the event? Is it responsibility of your class to "know" who will send the event?

Comment: In this concrete case, there is a class providing an event (C# event, not something abstract). And there is another class which needs to react on this event. ClassWithEvent implements an interface, so it's not a concrete implementation. Right now, only IClassWithEvent can raise this special event. I hope I answered your question.

Comment: The question is - is there a requirement which says that your class should react to events only from IClassWithEvent? Is there something which will make your class work incorrectly if the event is send from something else?

Comment: Currently only IClassWithEvent raises the event to which the class needs to react.

Comment: Then to the point - make something else to wire the event, not the ctor. I.e. something outside of these 2 classes.